# Printing info of a file/director (inode)

Tags: c, inode, fstat

I want to print some information of a directory. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat fileStat;
    int fd=0;
    if ( ( fd = open (argv[1] , O_RDONLY) ) == -1){
        perror ( "open " );
        exit (1) ;
    }

    if(fstat(fd, &fileStat)<0) return 1;

    printf("Information for %s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    --->printf("File Size: \t\t%d bytes\n",fileStat.st_size);
    printf("Number of Links: \t%d\n",fileStat.st_nlink);
    --->printf("File inode: \t\t%d\n",fileStat.st_ino);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting some warnings:

```
inode_test.c:24:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__off_t’ [-Wformat]

inode_test.c:26:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__ino_t’ [-Wformat]
```

Arrows show the line of each warning. Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. These formats are long unsigned int. So it's %lu. Anyway thanks for the help @haccks !

Comment: As a remark you can add the t/j addition specifier in front of the "lu" (but after the %)

Answer (score 0):

To print `__off_t` you need `%jd` specifier.

Comment: Still have warning. Either with %td or %jd.