# print Inode number in C

Tags: c, inode

How to get a listing of inode number of text files? in C

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *pFile;
    pFile=fopen("file.txt", "r");
       .
       .
       .
       .
    fclose(pFile);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I do not know how get inode.

Added by someone code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575727/printing-info-of-a-file-director-inode

Comment: M.S Chaudhari: How to specify for which files have show Information ?? Name my file is file.txt.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct ?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat fileStat;
    int fd=0;
    FILE *filename = "infile.txt";

    if ( ( fd = open (filename , O_RDONLY) ) == -1){
        perror ( "open " );
        system("pause");
        exit (1) ;
    }

    if(fstat(fd, &fileStat)<0) return 1;

    printf("Information for %s\n",filename);
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("File Size: \t\t%d bytes\n",fileStat.st_size);
    printf("Number of Links: \t%d\n",fileStat.st_nlink);
    printf("File inode: \t\t%d\n",fileStat.st_ino);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fileStat.st_ino return ino_t not int

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct stat fileStat;
        int fd=0;
        FILE *filename = "file1.txt";

        if ( ( fd = open (filename , O_RDONLY) ) == -1){
                perror ( "open " );
                system("pause");
                exit (1) ;
        }

        if(fstat(fd, &fileStat)<0) return 1;

        printf("File inode: %d\n",fileStat.st_ino);

        return 0;
}
```